# FOR loop with multiple values from two arrays in different configurations

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am working on a project involving calculating the work volume for a device.

Given that I have two angles, **beta1** and **beta2** between let's say 0-10 degrees ([deg] used for simplification here, in reality in [rad]),
I want to calculate the work volume for different combinations of e.g.

**beta1** = 1 [deg] 
and at the same time
**beta2** = 8 [deg]

I can't get my head around how to do it. I tried to cheat by running the FOR loop for 1000 values of **beta1** and then a random entry from the **beta2** array, but obviously it is not very reliable.

Here is the code: (it is a mess, but it is just trigonometry)

```
for ii=1:1000
   for jj=randi(1000)
T_0{ii} = [0 0 0 (l_joint/beta1(ii))*tan(beta1(ii)/2); 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1];
T_1{ii} = [cos(beta1(ii)) -sin(beta1(ii))*cos(alpha1) sin(beta1(ii))*sin(alpha1) ...
    ((l_joint/beta1(ii))*tan(beta1(ii)/2)+l_disk+(l_joint/beta2(ii))*tan(beta2(jj)/2))*cos(beta1(ii)); ...
    sin(beta1(ii)) cos(beta1(ii))*cos(alpha1) -cos(beta1(ii))*sin(alpha1) ...
    ((l_joint/beta1(ii))*tan(beta1(ii)/2)+l_disk+(l_joint/beta2(jj))*tan(beta2(jj)/2))*sin(beta1(ii)); ...
    0 sin(alpha1) cos(alpha1) 0; ...
    0 0 0 1];    
 T_2{ii} = [cos(beta2(jj)) -sin(beta2(jj))*cos(alpha2) sin(beta2(jj))*sin(alpha2) ...
    ((l_disk+(l_joint/beta2(jj))*tan(beta2(jj)/2)))*cos(beta2(jj)); ...
    sin(beta2(jj)) cos(beta2(jj))*cos(alpha2) -cos(beta2(jj))*sin(alpha2) ...
    ((l_disk+(l_joint/beta2(jj))*tan(beta2(jj)/2)))*sin(beta2(jj)); ...
    0 sin(alpha2) cos(alpha2) 0; ...
    0 0 0 1];

T_section{ii} = (T_0{ii}*T_1{ii}*T_2{ii})^n;
end end
```

Comment: I don't think you are being clear about your goal. You have two vectors beta1 and beta2 as well as some trigonometric function T_section that takes one value from beta1 and one from beta2 and computes a result, right? Now, do you want to compute all results for all combinations of b1 and b2 from the beta1 or beta2 vectors? If so, why do you index beta2 with random jj instead of jj=1:1000? In fact i don't understand what you mean by the "i tried to cheat... not very reliable".

Comment: That is right. Well, it means that I was wrong the whole time as I thought jj=1:1000 would exclude combinations such as beta1 = 8 [deg] and beta2 = 1 [deg]. So it doesn't? I guess I have to learn how the loops work again.

Comment: Well, if you do not know how a loop exactly works you really should learn that first and i won't describe this in general, because you can look in the docs or 1000s of tutorials on programming everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can work out, you have a function *T_section* with 2 parameters *beta1* and *beta2* and are asking how to calculate the value of the function *T_section(beta1, beta2)* for all combinations of *beta1* and *beta2*. You can calculate and visualize the results of a 2-D function in MATLAB like this:

```
beta1 = 0:0.1:10;
beta2 = 0:0.1:10;
[B1, B2] = meshgrid(beta1, beta2);
T_section = sind(10*B2)*cosd(20*B1); % replace with actual function
surf(beta1, beta2, T_section,'EdgeColor','none')
xlabel('\beta_1'); ylabel('\beta_2');
```

which yields this plot:

[image: 2-D function plot]

No need for loops here, vectorizing your calculations in MATLAB is very likely much faster (see the excellent MATLAB documentation, e.g. http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). You should probably also read the documentation about *meshgrid* (`doc meshgrid` on the console).